# how to use revoke all valid access/refresh tokens of a particular user in openiddict (2.0.1)

Tags: access-token, bearer-token, openiddict

Is there any way to trigger revoke all valid token of a user in openiddict version 2.0.1,
I added following code in my controller (took reference from Openiddict github issue #642 ,#380,#381)-
//code to use OPenIddictTokenManager class with dependency injection
OpenIddictTokenManager tokenManager

```
//logic to logout all active tokens//
foreach (var token in await _tokenManager.FindBySubjectAsync(user.Id))
{
if (await _tokenManager.IsValidAsync(token))
{
await _tokenManager.RevokeAsync(token);
}
}


And starup.cs file server options-

.AddServer(options =>
{
options.UseMvc();

                options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/***************");

                options
                    .AllowPasswordFlow()
                    .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
                    .AllowCustomFlow("id_token**")
                    .AllowCustomFlow("impers***")
                    .AllowCustomFlow("anony**")
                    .AllowCustomFlow("sms_t***");

                options.AcceptAnonymousClients();

                if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
                }
            })
            .AddValidation();


//I also tried with server and validation options.UseReferenceTokens(), but getting error: 401 "invalid_grant". Sometime 500 internal server error.

Can you please give any fix?
```